# How can I use the BANNED PUBG Mobile in India?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Just yesterday the Indian government banned PUBG Mobile along with 118 other Chinese Apps. As you guys know it is quite an addictive game and I am too addicted to it so is it possible I could still play the game without any problem (without using VPN)?

Answer (score 5):

If you want you could use a VPN with a server near India. If there are you will have some high ping but not that high. There is no possible way without VPN.